# Parsing xml with jQuery in IE6/7 issue

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer-6

I have some problem with parsing XML in Ie6/7(original 7 no compatible mode). On Another normal browsers it works.

Jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.xml",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('quoteresult').each(function(){
                var bid = $(this).find('bid').text();
                alert(bid);
            });

        }
});
```

When I do `alert(xml);` I see all XML file even in IE6, but `alert($(xml).html());` , In ie6 it is empty , in FF it works !!

I can't understand what is wrong !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your XML has no whitespace. As Firefox ignores it whereas IE6/7 breaks. You can add:

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
     alert(textStatus); 
}
```

to check for errors thrown back.

Comment: No, it doesn't have any space :(

Comment: dataType => The type of data expected from the server.

Comment: here I can't use datatype XML, just HTML

Comment: Try adding the code I have added above like you have with "success:" to see if any errors are thrown back.